# Java- Include function call within 'if' statement header?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, methods, boolean-operations

```
 public static boolean know(String [] [] t, int r , int c, String ){            
        boolean flag = false;                                                       
        if ((t[r-1][c-1]).equals(x+"_"));
            flag = true;
        return flag; 
}
```

above code is the method I'm trying to add within '`if`' statement.
does java allow to include function call within '`if`' statement(block).

Below snippet has an if statement block.

```
   if (know(t,1,2,"X")){
       return 3;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's legal.  Did you try it?

Comment: Why not try it for yourself?

Comment: Yes you can. You should try it

Comment: Sure you can; but you don't need to use a conditional for that logic: `return t[r-1][c-1].equals(x+"_");`.

Comment: You might want to remove the `;` on the end of your `if...` line, or your code always returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method in an if statement but the statement must evaluate to a boolean value. In your case you should close those brackets and declare x in the parameters to your known() method. Also you may come into a problem if you try to pass any 0s into that method because -1 is not a valid array index..

You are also calling the method know() which returns a true/false, but the equals() method will do that anyway so you can just use that wherever you call the know() method. Replace know(t[][] int, int, String) with....

```
 if (t[0][1].equals("X_")){
   return 3;
  }
```

if the inputs are dynamic then you can still do...

```
   if (t[input-1][input-1].equals(input+"_"))
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I found my mistake, I had an extra parentheses or something and when I recompiled the code it worked. And I'm using the "know" method to shortcut having to re-write hundreds of lines of tedious and error prone statements involving array indices. I'm making an advanced tic tac toe program.

Comment: dont forget to pass you x into the method too :)